# Active Record Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some issues in Rails Active Record Inheritance, I need to create a model that inherits parents class properties(fields) and should also hold its own properties.

Ex:
Parent Class

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Classes inheriting parent class (Content)

```
class Wiki < Content   // Inherting Class Content
end

class Video < Content   // Inherting Class Content
end
```

Suppose "content" table contains fields type,name (to store common fields)

- "Wiki" table contains fields body,description
- "Video" table contains fields filename,description

Inserting into content and wiki table as

```
def create
  WikiPage.new("name" =>"new_wikipage")
  @wiki_page = WikiPage.new(params[:wiki_page])
end
```

but, the problem is the newly created wikipage is not inserting(because the parent class "Content" is abstracting child class Wikipage param values)

Generating Error like method "body" not defined (field "body" is part of wiki table,which got hided by content table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails uses single-table inheritance (STI) for model subclasses.  This means that you don't create a separate table for Wiki or Video in your database.  They will all be stored in the "contents" table, and that table should include all the fields needed by all subclasses.

It's okay if not all subclasses use all the available fields.  Rails then keeps track of what subclass a record is, using the "type" column of the parent table.

I walk through this in detail in this article called [Single-Table Inheritance with Tests in Rails](http://kconrails.com/2010/01/26/single-table-inheritance-with-tests-in-ruby-on-rails/).  I think the code samples will give you a better idea of how to proceed.

Comment: What if you don't want to use STI though?

From the docs: "If you don’t have a type column defined in your table, single-table inheritance won’t be triggered. In that case, it’ll work just like normal subclasses with no special magic for differentiating between them or reloading the right type with find."

This question is about getting that working WITHOUT STI, which should be possible. I am having the same issue of having child classes with different attributes.

Comment: scragz: the question was about getting it working. The asker never said "without STI" because they probably didn't even know it was an option. Bottom line, class inheritance in ActiveRecord is done with STI. There are lots of good arguments against STI, and I avoid it when I can, but they don't matter. You can't have tables inheriting from each other in relational databases, so trying to emulate that behavior in AR classes is futile. Instead, try abstracting the common methods into a module that you then include in each class. Doing "rails g model content:wiki" would get the ball rolling.

Answer (score 1):

The technique you want to use is called *Single Table Inheritance*. Basically, only models which inherit directly from `ActiveRecord::Base` have their own table. That table should have a `type` column (required non-NULL) which stores the name of the class for each row/object.

You can read more about this in the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html). I've also written an [article on when to use STI](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html) which might be helpful.