# implement Active Record inheritance in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4

I want implement inheritance in rails with Active Record. I have 3 model:

1. Owner
2. Realowner
3. Legalowner

Realowner has 2 attribute: name and lastname

and legalowner has 2 attribute: mobile and legalnumber

[image]

Both of this 2 model inheritance from Owner. I try to model this with Active Record in rails. For this, I create `Owner` with `type` attribute:

```
rails g model owner type:string
```

and create `realowner` and `legalowner` with `scaffold`:

```
rails g scaffold realowner name:string lastname:sting
rails g scaffold legalowner mobile:string legalnumber:string
```

`Owner.rb`:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

`Realowner.rb`:

```
class Realowner < Owner
end
```

`Legalowner.rb`:

```
class Legalowner < Owner
end
```

I implement this in rails project, but when I want to create new `realowner` or `legalowner`, I get below error:

```
undefined method `name' for #<Realowner:0x00000005feff88>
undefined method `lastname' for #<Realowner:0x00000005feff88>
undefined method `mobile' for #<Legalowner:0x00000005feff88>
undefined method `legalnumber' for #<Legalowner:0x00000005feff88>
```

I resolved this problem by add this for attribute in `Owner` model. and when I create new `Realowner`, complete `type, name and last name` in Owner database and other field are empty and when I create new `Legalowner`, complete `type, mobile and legalnumber` in owner database and other field are empty too and both table of `Legalowner` and `Realowner` in database are empty.

How can I implement this inheritance with Active Record in rails? I want add attribute of classes in specific table in database. How can I do this? Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=active+record+inheritance and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148853/active-record-inheritence

Comment: What are you actually inheriting by your design? These two have different data, so sharing any behavior between them would be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Rails scaffolding doesn't support inheritance. So, you need to edit generated models and generate another migrations.

```
$ sed -i s/ActiveRecord::Base/Owner/ app/models/{realowner,legalowner}.rb
$ rm db/migrate/*_create_{real,legal}owners.rb
$ rails g migration AddFieldsToOwners name:string lastname:string mobile:string legalnumber:string
```

Comment: I want store data in specific data, not in one `Owner` table. I update the question and add models.